# HTML on page totally broken

Tags: html, css

I have made some changes to an HTML page where there is a lot going on, and I think I put something out of place, and now it is totally strange :)

This page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223

When you look at it from Firebug, it looks like the layout is closed way early, the footer is for some reason on the right side of the page, and links like "Existing Group Plans" are broken.

After staring at this for a while, I am not sure what is wrong.  Any idea what happened?

Comment: validator.w3.org/ is your friend.

Comment: Provide us with some HTML or CSS code, not links! We are interested in maintaining a community site with questions and answers, not looking at your private page!

Comment: Voted as too localized as you only give a link to your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [101 Validation Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Many won't cause your problem but there are a few that mention stray tags, etc. which can cause very serious negative effects to your layout.

> Line 678, Column 19: end tag for element "p" which is not open
>
> Line 510, Column 7: end tag for "head" which is not finished
>
> Line 579, Column 15: end tag for "ul" which is not finished
>
> Line 1023, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified

Comment: Thanks, making my way through them. Already fixed 2 issues. But that tool reports so much junk it is hard to know what to take serious.  Like that ul item...I see the closing tag for it...confusing :)

Comment: @GeekedOut, You have a `</ul>` tag but you may also have something _within_ the `<ul></ul>` that breaks the whole list.

Comment: @GeekedOut, Also keep in mind that Validator errors are commonly intertwined.  If you fix one, then one or two others may clear out along with it.  I would take the time to solve all 101 errors... you'll feel better and your problem will be solved.

Comment: yeah there is a nested ul, but that has been there for a while :) The current issue is with somet div closing the layout div waay too early.....I think thats the issue

Comment: @GeekedOut, Like I already said, fix one issue and a few others may drop off the list along with it.