# Why does the layout div close so early on this page and why is layout so broken?

Tags: html, css

I have this template I have been working with and I am really stuck on figuring out why the layout div is closed right away.

I looked at it with http://validator.w3.org and while there are many errors on the page, the main one is that there is some unbalance of closing and opening of divs. I am staring at it with firebug and nothing comes to mind as to why this is happening.

Any idea why the layout is so messed up here? http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223 and why the footer is appearing on the right side of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127308/html-on-page-totally-broken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the footer is appearing on the right side of the page because it is in your right column div:

`<div style="float: right; width: 240px;">`

Comment: that worked to fix the footer, but clicking on a link like "Existing Group Plans" still gives an error - would you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

add `</div>` before `<div class="footer">` , and add `clear:both;` to `.footer{}`

Comment: that worked to fix the footer, but clicking on a link like "Existing Group Plans" still gives an error - would you know how to fix that?

Comment: the link is not working because of `href="#" `, you need to put a correct adress there

Answer (score 1):

Your footer is inside the `<div float=right>` the contains the sidebar text. It cannot appear at the bottom of the page, only at the bottom of that div. If you want it to spread out at the very bottom of the, you'll have promote that footer div to be a direct child of the #layout div.

Comment: that worked to fix the footer, but clicking on a link like "Existing Group Plans" still gives an error - would you know how to fix that?

Comment: Check your JS console. In FF there's `uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://platform.twitter.com> to get poperty Proxy.InstalTrigger`. You're not loading the FB stuff properly, it would seem. No idea what's needed to fix that, I've worked very hard to not acknowledge FB's existence.